# Mapping local variables to instance variable in Camunda

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a local variable being set by my application in camunda.

I would like to map this to an instance variable "foo: after the task is complete, however I get an error when setting the value of an outputParameter "bar" to be ${foo}, the data types for both are string.

I cannot seem to find anything in the docs specifically stating ways to map localvariables to instance variables without writing custom java classes and using them as execution listeners(we are not trying to code any custom java within the camunda instance itself due to product requirements passed down from above), am I missing something or is this not existing functionality?

Comment: Where is the local variable set? On the task instance? On the execution that executes the user task?

Comment: on the task instance, we are not using any custom java and are solely integrating through the api I could rig up some of our code to sync the tasks through the api on completion, but I was assuming there was native functionality i am missing regarding mapping local task instance  variables to process instance variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the local variable in the **context of the execution** of the task in order to be mapped to process variables. So instead of calling REST method <strike>[Update/Delete Local Task Variables](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/local-variables/post-modify-local-task-variables/)</strike> you should call [Update/Delete Local Execution Variables](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/execution/local-variables/post-local-variables/)